# Show that B'BA = B'BC

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Problem statement: Given three matrixes $A_{m \times n}$, $B_{k \times m}$, $C_{m \times n}$, show that $B'BA = B'BC$ if and only if $BA = BC$.

My attempt:

If $BA = BC$, then $BA - BC = 0$

If $BA \ne BC$, then $BA - BC \ne 0$

$B'BA = B'BC = B'(BA - BC) = 0$ if and only if $BA - BC = 0$ (unless we assume $B'$ is zero, which is trivial)

Does my solution make sense? I feel like I'm missing the point and this is wrong.

Comment: Don't forget: it's perfectly common to multiply two nonzero matrices and get the zero matrix, in general. (This is why your solution isn't complete as written.)

Comment: Hint: you're trying to show that $B(A - C) = 0$ iff $B'B(A-C) = 0$.

Comment: @Ben Grossmann Do I need to use the dimensions of the matrices at all?

Comment: No, you don't. I would also suggest that it would be useful to begin with proving that $Bx = 0$ iff $B'Bx = 0$ in the case that $x$ is a column-vector.